# What do you call a 'quick' marriage?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, sentence-structure, idiom-request

If a couple get married shortly after they met each other and get divorced not long after their marriage. What do you call their marriage? Or how do you describe this situation?

Comment: In addition to divorce (or annulment),there are different terms for a brief marriage in some cultures. For example, Islam has the concept *mutʿah*, https://www.britannica.com/topic/mutah, a temporary marriage. In that case, the word would be borrowed into English from Arabic (or *sigheh*, from Farsi, for the same concept).

Comment: A "quick" marriage would be one that took place fairly soon after the two people met, and/or one where the ceremony itself didn't take long. For your context I'd refer to [*their **short-lived** marriage*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22their+short-lived+marriage%22) (the same as countless writers over the centuries).

Comment: The simple answer is there is **no term or slang in English** for this.

Comment: Quick marriage doesn't automatically make me think they got divorced. Makes me think just got married quickly or even eloped.

Comment: Related, but not synonymous, in American English is the term "Shotgun Wedding", which refers to a marriage that is hastily arranged and performed after the bride becomes pregnant (and, often, not long after the bride and groom have met).

Comment: *marriage was short lived* takes off pretty good after 1960 according to ngram. @FumbleFingers - answers belong down there ;)

Comment: *A short ceremony*. .... What do you call a marriage that doesn't last very long?

Comment: @Mazura: I'm not convinced "short-lived" is any better than DrMoishe Pippik
's suggested [***mutʿah***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22mut%CA%BFah%22) - which seems to have hundreds of written instances in Google Books. The OP needs to specify whether he's asking about marriages that don't last long through ***failure*** or ***design.***

Comment: "impulsive and short-lived" would probably be the pithiest description of a marriage that both occurs soon after the partners meet, and collapses as quickly.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I agree, *Shotgun Wedding* came to mind. Supposedly so-called because the groom is forced (by threat of shotgun) into the wedding by the bride's father, so the bride/family do not suffer the shame of a baby out of wedlock.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Both "short marriage" and "quick marriage" work, but "quick marriage" is more often used to mean a short wedding ceremony, or getting married with a very short engagement period, so a sentence like, "Marsha and John had a quick marriage" could mean three different things, depending on the context.

A "short marriage", however, only has one meaning, which is that the time between the wedding and the divorce was short.

Answer (score 14):

I would call it **brief marriage** or **trial marriage**.

[Brief](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brief) (Merriam Webster Dictionary) short in duration, extent, or length.

[Trial marriage](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trial%20marriage) (Merriam Webster Dictionary) a proposed form of marriage in which a man and woman are married but for only a stated period.

Comment: trial marriage seems to imply a fixed period known beforehand, the case here doesn't sound like that

Comment: I agree. However trial period cannot  be long, otherwise it won't be a trial.

Answer (score 10):

It can be ambiguous to talk about the length of the *marriage*, because that can be interpreted as the length of the marriage *ceremony*.

However, you could say that the couple *were married for* a short time.  That's clear that you're talking about the period from marriage to divorce (as that's when they are no longer married).

Alternatively, using an adverb - they married *briefly* (but not "quickly", as that could mean soon after meeting).  Or not mention the marriage, but imply it, by saying they were *soon divorced*.

Comment: To me _marriage_ meaning _wedding ceremony_ is old fashioned and stilted, so I would not find the phrase ambiguous in that way unless there was some reason to think the word was not being used normally.

Comment: @Colin, that's reasonable, as I'm becoming more old-fashioned as I age.  That said, there are plenty of English-language users older than me, so it's wise to take a sample of views into account!

Answer (score 6):

A US-specific term may be **Hollywood marriage** or **celebrity marriage**.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_marriage):

> The term has grown to also have strong negative connotations of a marriage that is of short duration and quickly ends in separation or divorce.  The term developed the negative connotations fairly early; by the 1930s, a "Hollywood marriage" was a marriage both glamorous and short-lived.

Comment: ***short-lived*** +1

Answer (score 4):

I would call that a [whirlwind](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whirlwind) marriage.

Comment: I've heard it said as a "whirlwind courtship" to imply it was brief, but not so much applied to the marriage afterward.

Answer (score 3):

I'd just say the marriage was "short".  A "quick" marriage is one with a short betrothal or a short ceremony.  "John met Sarah and two days later they went to Vegas for a quick marriage".

Of course there could be some specific context to this, depending on the reason for getting divorced soon after marriage.

Alternatively you could use the actual length of the marriage.  "John's short, five-day marriage ended in annulment..."

Answer (score 0):

They married quickly and divorced just as quickly.

They married shortly after meeting and divorced shortly after marrying.

*Or, be specific:*

They knew each other two months before marrying. They were married three months before divorcing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call it a loose knot. Quickly tied together without caution, easily unwound. Inspired by the idiom, "Tying the knot" (as in getting married)

Comment: Is this something you made up yourself, or have you seen it used by other people? If possible, provide references.

Comment: I made it up myself. I haven't seen it be used.